# Can't find doc or answer about this Mongo error

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

{"ok":0,"code":4031700,"codeName":"Location4031700","name":"MongoError"}}

Hi,

I found anything about this error.
Nor on [error doc](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/35079a95ebc591dee47ecca5e0f22eb7a7381fd0/docs/errors.md) or on internet.

This error comes from an aggregation pipeline with a $match, $lookup and $facet.
I can't connect to the server, I think it is probably a broken document causing the error.

Anyone ever encountered this error ?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the aggregation pipeline. The linked code is 9 years old, so maybe a bit outdated.

Comment: Took me a few seconds - [document_source_facet.cpp](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/pipeline/document_source_facet.cpp): *"document constructed by $facet is <<usedBytes>> bytes, which exceeds the limit of <<maxBytes>> bytes"*.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Wow thank you very much, how did you find this information ?

Comment: I googled for `mongodb 4031700` - then it was the third entry.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a few seconds - document_source_facet.cpp: "document constructed by $facet is <> bytes, which exceeds the limit of <> bytes". –
Wernfried Domscheit

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).